# Connect to the database by reading the password from a text file

Tags: mysql, database, python-3.x, passwords, database-connection

I defined a connection for connecting to the database, but now I want to connect a password from a text file. Connected here is a mistake. Someone has a better idea?

```
import pymysql

ccc=pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',port=3306,user='root',password =(po),db='mysql')
bak=ccc.cursor()
print(bak.execute("SELECT User FROM mysql.user;"))

ccc.close()
bak.close()

def po():
 with open('C:/Users/PycharmProjects/u2/Ntt.txt') as o:
    for i in o:
        print(i)



po()
```

I want this program to write a password from a text file

Comment: Hi @nick. First of all, Welcome to SO. Your code has logical error. The po() function should return the password string . You are just printing it  
I hope this will help

Comment: Thankful. But did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. It works in my environment. Also when you are putting code segments to SO, try to maintain the code format by using the **curly brackets** mark in the tool bar.

```
import pymysql


    def po():
    with open('C:/Users/PycharmProjects/u2/Ntt.txt') as o:
        for i in o:
            return i


ccc = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', password=po(), db='mysql')
bak = ccc.cursor()
print(bak.execute("SELECT User FROM mysql.user;"))

ccc.close()
bak.close()
```

Comment: Yes, as you said. Thank you